# It is possible to push from FMS to multiple FMS?

Tags: video, flash, adobe-flash, rtmp

I'm using adobe FMS, and i'd like to configure my central FMS to push live content to several out-of-site FMS servers. is it possible? or can FMS only pull data from another FMS?

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer to this: yes, but a script is necessary for it.
there's an adobe documentation for this
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashmediaserver/devguide/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d11a0773d56e-7ffb.html